# How to add subtext to axes in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes, subtitle

For the main y-axis and x-axis, I have generic titles like "Tank's Ratio" and "Counts". I want a second line of label where I specify the ratio and counts. eg. Just below "Tank's Ratio" I want "# in water/# in sand" in a smaller font but along the y-axis. Similarly for the x-axis.
Here is the basic code

```
data <- data.frame(set = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), density = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3), counts = c(100, 2, 3, 76, 33, 12, 44, 13, 54, 36, 65, 1), ratio = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 90, 1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = counts, y = ratio)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ylab("Tank's Ratio") + 
  xlab("Counts")
```

Comment: I'm not sure about resizing the font, but you can add a newline character (\n) to the ylab. Try `ggplot(data,aes(x=counts, y=ratio)) + geom_point() +ylab("Tank's Ratio \n#in water/# in sand") + xlab("Counts") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but hope it helps:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
```

First, create plot without ylab:

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = counts, y = ratio)) + 
  geom_point()  +
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("Counts")
```

Then add subtitle for both axis:

```
g2 <- grid.arrange(g, 
                   bottom = textGrob("in water/ # in sand", 
                                     x = 0.55, y = 1, gp = gpar(fontsize = 9)),
                   left = textGrob("in water/ # in sand",  rot = 90, 
                                   x = 1.5, gp = gpar(fontsize = 9)))
```

And finally, add description of y-axis

```
grid.arrange(g2, 
             left = textGrob("Tank's Ratio",  rot = 90, 
                             x = 1.7, gp = gpar(fontsize = 12)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add x and main titles.

**EDIT:** This is ridiculously slooow!

```
  #library(extrafont)
#loadfonts(dev="win")
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
ggplot(aes(x=counts, y=ratio)) + geom_point() +
labs(y=expression(atop(bold("Tank's Ratio"),atop(italic("#in water #in sand")))))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15,family="Comic Sans MS"))
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL:**

```
library(tidyverse) 

      data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=counts, y=ratio)) + geom_point() +
    labs(y="Tank's Ratio \n #in Water#in sand")
```

Comment: This doesn't use smaller font size as OP wanted.

Comment: Edited but I think it's too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code, defining the margins, the axis titles and sub-titles yourself:

We use `theme` to increase the bottom and left margin, and to suppress the automatically generated axis titles.

We use `annotate` to generate the text that serves as axis title and sub-title, if necessary, the text is rotated.

We generate the plot, turn it in a `grob`, and with this `grob` we can turn of clipping, and show the plot.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = counts, y = ratio, group = 1)) +
  geom_point()  + 

  ## increase margin size for left and bottom and
  ## remove the axis titles
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 4, 4), "lines"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank() ) +

  ## define the plotting area to NOT include the annotations
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 100), ylim= c(0, 100), expand = FALSE) +

  ## annotate y axis
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -9, y = 50, label = "Tank's Ratio", angle = 90, size = 5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -5, y = 50, label = "#in water/#in sand", angle = 90, size = 4) +

  ## annotate x axis
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 50, y = -5, label = "Counts", size = 5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 50, y = -9, label = "#in water/#in sand", size = 4)

## turn off  clipping for axis extra labels
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
g2$layout$clip[g2$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid::grid.draw(g2)
```

This yields the following picture:

[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.